# Yii2 relation with 4 tables involved

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-model

I have 2 models I'd like to get relation via 2 tables in the middle. Crazy, uh?

```
MODEL A    MODEL B    MODEL C   MODEL D
id         id         id        id
...        A.id       D.id      ...
...        C.id       ...       ...
...        ...        ...       ...
```

I'm in the MODEL D class, and I'd like to have how many A's there are, passing through C and B.
I've tried with viaTable, via, joinWith's, but I couldn't get the logic :-(

Is this possible with Yii ActiveRecord relational stuff or is a simple DB custom query better?

Comment: ->joinWith(“c.b.a”)

Comment: Can you show what you tried?